# Array destructuring in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I've got a variable `data` which comes in one of the following two formats:

1. `[1,2,3]`
2. `[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]`

At some point I need to parse this data and so I do:

```rb
main, alternative = data
```

While case (2) works as expected, (1) doesn't.
Instead it sets:

```rb
main=1 
alternative=2 
# 3 is dropped.
```

My end goal however is this:

```rb
main=[1,2,3] 
alternative=nil
```

What's the most elegant way to do this? Ideally I'd like to avoid conditionals and long methods...

Comment: I would you a conditional because it is much easier to understand what is going on which makes the code easier to read and maintain in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My honest answer here is *don't pass data around in a fuzzy, poorly-defined structure*. If at all possible, improve the underlying caller to send consistently-defined objects.

However if you're looking for a quick patch, then how about:

```
# data comes in one of the following two formats:
# 1. [1,2,3]
# 2. [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]
# So, this patch enforces some consistency in the structure:
data = [data, nil] unless data.first.is_a?(Array)

main, alternative = data
```

Comment: You are perfectly right. However at this point the structure is out of my control. 
Your solution seems to do the trick..Thnx!

Comment: Since Ruby is a duck-typing language you might want to check if something can be treated as array (`to_ary`) rather then checking the class. `data.first.respond_to?(:to_ary)` This is not necessary better or worse than checking the class, but just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to be running on ruby 2.7 or 3, you can use pattern matching:

```rb
case data
in [Array => main, Array => alternative]
  # here `main` and `alternative` are bound to the expected items
  # because the match succeeds by type.
in main
  # now main is bound but alternative might still be bound to the previous
  # clause, so don't use it.
  alternative = nil
end
```

A more fluent, but still correct, way would be

```rb
data in [Array => main, Array => alternative] or data in Array => main

# now main and alternative are as expected
```

If the structure (length) of the array is known beforehand to be 3, you might also be comfortable with

```
data in [[_,_,_] => main, [_,_,_] => alternative] or data in [_,_,_] => main
```

so you have less false negatives.